# ng-repeat doesn't display anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<div class="" ng-repeat="data in mydata">
  {{data.b.three}}
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {

$scope.mydata = [{
    "a":"",
    "b":[{
        "one":"",
        "two":  "",
        "three": "1"
        }]
}]

}
```

I expect it will return '1' but it didn't, also there is no error message in my console.

Comment: hint: `b` is an array, so it does not have a `three` property.

Comment: Did you declare your Ctrl as an angular Ctrl using angular.module(...).controller(...)?

Comment: try {{data.b[0].three}} or remove the braces from b in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

Html :

```
<div ng-app="print" ng-controller="Ctrl ">
<div  ng-repeat="data in mydata">
  {{data.b[0].three}}
</div>
```

JS :

```
angular.module('print', []).
controller('Ctrl',function ($scope) {

$scope.mydata = [{
    "a":"",
    "b":[{
        "one":"",
        "two":  "",
        "three": "1"
        }]
}]

});
```

You can find all here : https://jsfiddle.net/k0tx4qzv/